# Access point for small business hotspot

Tags: wifi, networking, router, access-point

I'd like to create a free hotspot wifi in my cafè to get email/phone number (previous agreement of the user) from my clients. In other words, I want an access point with costumizable captive portal. I see that exists the Ubiquiti access point but they require to buy the Cloud key to work correctly, right? Otherwise there is the TP-Link EAP 245/225 that are compatible with Facebook Wifi (to get like on a facebook page) but I don't understand if I can set a personalized authenticathion page where I can get all data that I need.

Another lowcost solution for do that is using a raspberry with a custom OS as ZeroShell but I don't know if the performance is good or not.

There are others simple systems to do that? I search a low cost solution. I expect to have a load of 25-30 person simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

In a real world scenario, around 25-30 per AP gets the best out of the bandwidth of the access points. If you wanna a simple configuration, [FS AP-D1750](https://www.fs.com/products/20013.html) is recommended, its software is based on the OpenWRT program and updated through U -BOOT technology. This frees you from the application selection and configuration provided by the vendor and allows you to customize the device through the use of packages to suit any application.